# Can you create an array and iterate over it in a handlebars template?

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebars.net

In *handlebars.js* or *handlebars.net*, is there a way to create an array and iterate over it in the template? I would like to do something like this:

```
<select name="hour">
  {{#each [1..24]}}
    <option>{{this}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

I understand that I can create custom helpers to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions like this are not supported. Your best bet is as you said, use a helper.